# MS Access-how to check if a field value equals the previous record?

Tags: date, ms-access, rows

I have a table in MS Access that contains Store_code,Year,Month,Day and some other columns that is sorted by the respective order of the columns that I mentioned.
like this:

```
Store_code Year Month Day
65         2017  11   6
65         2017  11   6
```

I have made some other checks for the other columns and I want now to create a new column called Day_Valid where if the Day in a row equals the previous one it becomes 1 else it becomes 0

like this:

```
Store_code Year Month Day Day_valid
65         2017  11   6    
65         2017  11   6    1
65         2017  11   7    0
65         2017  11   7    1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, need a subquery that pulls value from previous record. This requires a unique identifier field - autonumber should serve. http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

If you want this comparison for each store/year/month, consider:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.Day FROM Table4 AS Dupe 
   WHERE Dupe.Store_code=Table4.Store_code AND Dupe.Year=Table4.Year 
   AND Dupe.Month=Table4.Month AND Dupe.ID<Table4.ID 
   ORDER BY Dupe.ID DESC) = [Day] AS Day_Valid 
FROM Table4;
```

Be aware this type of nested query can perform slowly with large dataset.

Year and Month are reserved words - should not use reserved words as names for anything.